# Reading and modifying the HTTP GET request in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I would like to read and modify (add) HTTP headers in a Chrome extension. I am using the chrome.webRequest API for the same. But i am still not able to read it. Here's my code.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(

    function(details) {
    details.requestHeaders.push({name:"dummyHeader",value:"1"});
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    },

    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestHeaders"]

);
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `"blocking"` flag to the ExtraInfoSpec list in order to pause the request. Without this flag, the return value of an `onBeforeSendHeaders` event listener is ignored.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        details.requestHeaders.push({name:"dummyHeader",value:"1"});
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]
                      //^^^^^^^^
);
```

I suggest to read the documentation more carefully, in particular the [Registering event listeners](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#subscription) section.

Answer (score 1):

But, for all reading it later, it is not solution for XmlHttpRequest.

It is not obvious but asynchronous request can't be block. More about this issue you can read at [issiue 132731](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132731)
If you need to change request headers for XmlHttpRequest you must use [declarativeWebRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html)

An example of implementation you can find at Chrome Rest Client [background page](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/source/browse/trunk/RestClient/war/extension/background.js) (declarativeRequest.setRules() function).