# Setting XHR header 'Referer' in Chrome app

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to set header 'Referer' in my Chrome app.
When I do it this way:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Referer', 'http://example.com/');
```

an error shows:

> ajax.js:15 Refused to set unsafe header "Referer"

I found an old topic here where someone modified 'Referer'  using chrome.webRequest but this extension is not available now in Chrome apps.
**Chrome.webRequest isn't working anymore! All topics on SO recommend using it but it's not supported anymore by chrome.**
How to change this header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set referer for xml.HTTP.Request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218525/set-referer-for-xml-http-request)

Comment: At the time that question was asked, someone bypassed it using chrome.webRequest. So there may be some new way to bypass it.

Comment: @MatixYo you could take a look at the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960902/reading-and-modifying-the-http-get-request-in-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[web-server-chrome](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) includes a [ChromeSocketXMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/blob/master/chromesocketxhr.js) object.
You could use it in your project. You can clone the repository and run minimize.sh to get a minimized, single file, to include in your project. You can then use the ChromeSocketXMLHttpRequest as a standin for the normal XHR

Answer (score 2):

While the API is not available to Chrome Apps' own requests, [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) has a [`request` interface](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#property-request) that implements `webRequest` and allows you to modify requests coming from it.

This way, you can make a "proxy" page that will do XHR's for you, embed it in a webview, and modify its requests. It's an extra hoop, but at least it's possible.